# How can I get the session value in code behind from handler page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I am using uploadify to upload a audio file. It uses the handler upload.ashx to upload the file to the server. I want to get the file path in my aspx page. So I am  set a session value in handler so that I get the file path in aspx but I am not able to do so. How can I get the value of file path from handler to .aspx page

```
   public class Upload : IHttpHandler,IRequiresSessionState        {   
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)         {        
    string savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);     
    context.Session["VideoFile"] = savepath;     }  }
```

In my aspx page when I try to get the file path

```
      DocLink = Session["VideoFile"].ToString();
```

the session value is always null. How can I get the session value in code behind

```
 string path= HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["VideoFile"].ToString();
```

I tried this, even this is null

Answer (score 0):

If you call it with the context like `context.Session["VideoFIle"]` and everything is ok, then the second possible reason is that you do not have setup correct the path on the cookies properties.

Check and set the domain on the httpCookies on web.config to be sure that is with out the `www.` and be able to read it from any page started on your domain

```
<httpCookies domain="domain.com" httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" />
```

Why is that, because if you do not set the domain on cookies then the cookie is writed with the domain that its read from the url, and the session is connected to the cookie. If your domain change, eg you call it with `www.domain.com`, and in one page call you use `domain.com` then the cookie is not the same, and the session is not the same.

### Note

Inside your handler the context is comming from the parametre that calling the `ProcessRequest` and not from `HttpContext.Current.Request`. Maybe this is one more issue on your code.