# Session not maintaining in asp page from handler

Tags: asp.net

In our Project, I am assigning `context.Session["StackImgInsert"]="some string"` in asp.net handler(.ashx page).
Now I want to make `Session["StackImgInsert"]=null`  in ASP Page (.aspx) when I read value of `Session["StackImgInsert"]`, then it is displaying as `null`.
Can anyone tell how to read the session from handler and make it null.

Comment: You assign null and then it's null, what a huge surprise.

Comment: Read your question and tell me, honestly - does your question make sense to you? Would you understand it if you were us?

Comment: So you have successfully set the set the session value in your ashx to "some string". Now you have a problem to set it to `null`? Replace `"some string"` with `null` in that code.

Comment: i hav set session value to some string in ashx page. Now I want to make that session value "null" in my ascx page(not aspx page, which i mentioned earlier). But when i read that session value in my ascx page, the value is always null. Now when i go back to my ashx page, for further functionalities, the session is still shown. The prob here is i can't read that session value and make it null in my ascx page_load() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this `IReadOnlySessionState` in your class name as follows

```
 public class GetFeatures : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
 {
      context.Session["StackImgInsert"]="some string";
 }
```

Comment: IReadOnlySessionState is only for Reading session in that handler. I used IRequiresSessionState, which is for reading and setting the session value in handler, which is working fine in Handler. But, in .aspx page, i can't read that session value.

Comment: the reason could be you are reading the values before handler call.

Comment: handler is firing first, then in the page_load() which is in .aspx page, i am not able to read that particular session value

Comment: are you calling `handler` on the same web page through jQuery?

Comment: i hav set session value to some string in ashx page. Now I want to make that session value "null" in my ascx page(not aspx page, which i mentioned earlier). But when i read that session value in my ascx page, the value is always null. Now when i go back to my ashx page, for further functionalities, the session is still shown. The prob here is i can't read that session value and make it null in my ascx page_load() method

Comment: yes...i am calling the handler and the handler in ascx page and trying to read that session value in ascx.cs page

Comment: The session is same in `ascx` or `aspx`. The only reason I fell is that you are checking the session value before assigning any value to it.

Comment: The page load will be first call and then after any jquery call will be done **In case you are calling handler through jquery**

Comment: i don't think so. First jquery handler fires, then page postback fires, which fires page_load() then [here handler fires first, where session value is set, then page postback happens, but during postback in the page_load() the session value is null] which is d issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065436/how-can-i-get-the-session-value-in-code-behind-from-handler-page?rq=1

Comment: i found similar post here .. was dat d issue??

Comment: a last question are you calling your handler through jQuery??

Comment: yes.through uploadify, which is in jquery..i am actually doing uploading an image functionality, for vch code is in ashx page

Comment: and any jQuery will be called after rendering your page `(aspx and ascx)`. Means after page load of both `aspx and ascx`

Comment: i am not saying about the page_load() for the first time that's happening. When page is rendered totally, when i clicked on upload button then that jquery fires vch further fires ashx page, then postback is done, vch fires that particular ascx page_load()

Comment: Finally i got my answer...the session id for the session in the handler(ashx) and session id for the session in my page(aspx) are different....

Comment: so the session value id different in my handler and aspx page....i don't know the exact reason but they are different...hence the session values are different in handler and aspx page....